# Avoid multiple try catch in python3

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have created my custom exception and placed that in django settings file.

I have a created a create api operation.My api takes data as input and calls multiple third party create api's if any one fails it reverts create operation of all third party api's.

```
class InsertionOrderViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):   #my api
    ''' Manages insertion order dsp operations'''
    def create(self, request, format=None):
         try:
                // create api 1
         except error as e:
                 return e
         try:
                // create api 2
         except error as e:
                 // undo api 1
                 return e
         try:
                // create api 3
         except error as e:
                 // undo api 1
                 // undo api 2
                 return e
```

Is there a way to avoid writing multiple try catch in such rollback scenerios?

Comment: Why. this is perfectly fine (if you really need to do this kind of depending inserts/rollbacks and can not simplyfy it)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I'm thinking this should give you the same output like that.

```
class InsertionOrderViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):  # my api
"""Manages insertion order dsp operations"""

def create(self, request, format=None):
    try:
        # create api 1
    except error as e:
        # undo api 1
        # create api 2
    except error2 as e:
        # undo api 2
        # create api 3
    except Exception as e:
        return e
```